# Which versions of ffmpeg support "Encrypted fmp4"?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, mp4, video-encoding

Using `ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`, I *think* it successfully converted an input mp4 file to encrypted files: `list_1080p_0000.m4s  list_1080p_0001.m4s  list_1080p_0002.m4s  list_1080p.m3u8  list.m3u8 list_init.mp4`

But I later upgraded to `ffmpeg version 4.2.2-0york0~18.04` and received an error when trying to re-run the same command: `[hls @ 0x563f97298000] Encrypted fmp4 not yet supported`

Given that the newer version of ffmpeg says that "Encrypted fmp4 not yet supported", I'm wondering whether my earlier version wasn't really encrypted at all. How can I tell?

**And how can I learn which versions of ffmpeg support encrypted fmp4?**

P.S. The reason I wanted to upgrade was because I hoped that [what I experienced here (that the init.mp4 was created at the root folder instead of alongside the m3u8 file) was a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460212/how-to-fix-ext-x-mapuri-in-m3u8-when-specifying-absolute-hls-fmp4-init-filename) and that newer versions of ffmpeg would create the list_init.mp4 in the correct folder, which I still think might be the case.

Comment: have you tried Bento4? "MPEG Common Encryption (CENC) as specified in ISO/IEC 23001-7" is one example: https://github.com/axiomatic-systems/Bento4

Comment: @vssher I'll consider that if I can't get ffmpeg working (which would be much more convenient since my current libraries use that). Thanks.